# ctrl f search only model popup html data

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome

I want ctrl F search text only on model popup not in whole body.

```
 ngAfterViewInit(){
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
    if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) &&(String.fromCharCode(event.which).toLowerCase() == 'f')) {
     if (window.getSelection) {
       var range = document.createRange();
       range.selectNode(document.getElementById('search'));
       var sel = window.getSelection();
       sel.removeAllRanges();
       sel.addRange(range);
    }
  }
});
}
```

[image]

Comment: Browser `Ctrl+F` is to search occurrences on whole page. Your modal and body both are parts of the same page. There is no way here than to pop-out the window you have in the image there and search in it.

Comment: can we change Ctrl+F property using javascript?

Comment: @anandsingh There is no way to change the Ctrl+F property. There is a way around it though. You can run `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the Ctrl+F browser popup. After that, use DOM manipulation to create your own Ctrl+F popup and will search through the popup that you created.